# Will all linear band inversions of non-degenerate bands change chern number by one?

Tags: topological-insulators

I have learned from literature that band touching is the source of chern number.In three dimensional material, any non-degenerate linear band crossing will form a weyl point which is a monopole of berry flux. So in two dimensions, will a non-degenerate linear band inversion guarantee a change in chern number? By linear, I mean that at the critical point, the band touching are linear in $k$.

Comment: Not every band crossing gives you a Weyl point, it depends on how they cross. And there is no Chern number in 3D.

Comment: Really? I am told that a general band crossing $k\cdot p$ hamiltonian gives a monopole of chern number. What kind of a band crossing does not form a weyl point?

Comment: Chern number for topological band structure has a very specific meaning, and there is simply no such thing in 3D. A generic crossing point of two bands, linearized near the band touching, indeed gives you $\sigma\cdot p$, but one needs to make sure that the Weyl points are well separated in momentum space. There are also Dirac semimetals, which roughly speaking have two Weyl points sitting on top of each other, and are protected by lattice symmetries.

Comment: Oh, by carrying a chern number, I mean evaluate the chern number of a closed surface in which there is a weyl point. Unless forbidden by symmetry, band crossings are always linear because it is the first order perturbation. I edited my questions accordingly.

Comment: OK, it is still hard to make sense of your question though. In 2D, it makes no sense to talk about monopole of Berry flux of band crossing point because there are only two momentum directions. With additional symmetry, you can classify the winding number of the band crossing point. On the other hand, you can ask about Chern number of occupied bands in an insulator (of course not touched with others). So what do you actually mean?

Comment: you can regard the parameter which controls the band gap as the third momentum direction. And by chern number, I mean chern number of occupied bands.